# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl

I am facing the below error while executing an SSIS package on a remote server. I am using Windows authentication in my local environment and it's working fine without any issues. I maintain a package.config file for my variables to be deployed in other environments.

While running the built package in other remote servers with a connection string of that environment in package.config as per the server, it's failing.

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'abc\xyz'

I am unable to find the cause of this error.

Comment: Are you trying to use a windows authentication of a machine on other machines??!!

Comment: yes, but my login account has permission on all the other machines too where I want to deploy it..

Comment: @BijayNandagiri are you running this package from SQL agent Job or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the package from a SQL agent Job than you have to add a proxy account, you can follow one of these links for a step-by-step asnwer.

- [Running a SSIS Package from SQL Server Agent Using a Proxy Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/)
- [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy)

Comment: Hi ,I am using Batch job not sql job...batch job is nothing but running a sequence of batch scripts which runs on batch account

Comment: Why not using SQL authentication?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a proxy account or can you just use the SQL Server Agent service account, assuming the service account is a domain/network account with permission to the SQL database and to the SSIS package location? What does a proxy account add over that method?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved for me after adding the account in the users list of the database.