# Error 0x80040E4D when running a dtsx package from agent sql job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I get this error:

```
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.6300.2 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.     
Started:  2:05:09 PM
```

> Could not load package "\DATAX\Lettersend" because of error 0xC0014062.
> Description: The LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80040E4D (Login failed for user 'Warehouse\SQLServ$'.).
> The SQL statement that was issued has failed.

I configured a job that lives on a server and tries to run a dtsx packages "Lettersend" living on another one.

I have tried running the dtsx package on the server where is living and it runs correctly. But trying to run with the job, it throws this error.

Comment: Login failed is your issue.  When you run it from the job it runs as the user the SQL agent runs as (or you assign in the job) and whatever that login that is being used to run the job does not have access.

Comment: You can almost always google the error code and context to find information and fixes about them. Here's another user that had the same issue and resolved it in a couple simple steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237922/ssis-error-code-dts-e-oledberror-an-ole-db-error-has-occurred-error-code-0x80